# Google Web Toolkit (GWT) offline documentation

Tags: gwt

Perhaps I'm missing something simple here, but is there any place to download the GWT documentation for use offline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download the SDK [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html) you will have it in

`yourGWTFolder\doc\javadoc\index.html`

Where 'yourGWTFolder' is the folder you unzipped the file you downloaded to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try someting like:

`wget --no-check-certificate -k -r -np -p https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/`

I do not know if `wget` is available on Windows. If not you can use cygwin or a linux VM.